# Convert Survival Data from Wide to Long

Tags: r, reshape, survival-analysis

I am reading http://www.uk.sagepub.com/books/Book233417 and the `Rcmdr` is used to transform the Rossi data http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Fox-Companion/Rossi.txt from wide to long for time-varying survival analysis.

The `Rcmdr` script to do the transformation is:

```
.CovSets <-structure(list(covariate.1 = c("emp1", "emp2", "emp3", "emp4", "emp5", "emp6", "emp7", "emp8", "emp9", "emp10", "emp11", "emp12", "emp13", "emp14", "emp15", "emp16", "emp17", "emp18", "emp19", "emp20", "emp21", "emp22", "emp23", "emp24", "emp25", "emp26", "emp27", "emp28", "emp29","emp30", "emp31", "emp32", "emp33", "emp34", "emp35", "emp36", "emp37", "emp38", "emp39", "emp40", "emp41", "emp42", "emp43", "emp44", "emp45", "emp46", "emp47", "emp48", "emp49", "emp50", "emp51", "emp52")), .Names =  "covariate.1")
Rossi.long <- unfold(Rossi, time="week", event="arrest", cov=.CovSets, 
                                         cov.names=c("covariate.1"))
remove(.CovSets)
```

**However this script does not run if the `Rcmdr` is not loaded.**

The results of the Rcmdr script transforms the Rossi dataframe from

```
> head(Rossi,20)
   week arrest fin age race wexp mar paro prio educ emp1 emp2 emp3 emp4 emp5 emp6 emp7 emp8 emp9 emp10 emp11 emp12 emp13 emp14 emp15 emp16 emp17 emp18 emp19 emp20 emp21 emp22 emp23 emp24 emp25
1    20      1   0  27    1    0   0    1    3    3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
2    17      1   0  18    1    0   0    1    8    4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
3    25      1   0  19    0    1   0    1   13    3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
4    52      0   1  23    1    1   1    1    1    5    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
5    52      0   0  19    0    1   0    1    3    3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
6    52      0   0  24    1    1   0    0    2    4    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1
7    23      1   0  25    1    1   1    1    0    4    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0    NA    NA
8    52      0   1  21    1    1   0    1    4    3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     1     1
9    52      0   0  22    1    0   0    0    6    3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
10   52      0   0  20    1    1   0    0    0    5    0    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
11   52      0   1  26    1    0   0    1    3    3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
12   52      0   0  40    1    1   0    0    2    5    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
13   37      1   0  17    1    1   0    1    5    3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
14   52      0   0  37    1    1   0    0    2    3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
15   25      1   0  20    1    0   0    1    3    4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0
16   46      1   1  22    1    1   0    1    2    3    0    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
17   28      1   0  19    1    0   0    0    7    3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
18   52      0   0  20    1    0   0    0    2    3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
19   52      0   0  25    1    0   0    1   12    3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
20   52      0   0  24    0    1   0    1    1    3    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
   emp26 emp27 emp28 emp29 emp30 emp31 emp32 emp33 emp34 emp35 emp36 emp37 emp38 emp39 emp40 emp41 emp42 emp43 emp44 emp45 emp46 emp47 emp48 emp49 emp50 emp51 emp52 id
1     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA  1
2     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA  2
3     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA  3
4      0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1  4
5      1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0  5
6      1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0  6
7     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA  7
8      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0  8
9      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1  9
10     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0 10
11     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1 11
12     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1 12
13     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA 13
14     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1 14
15    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA 15
16     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA 16
17     0     0     0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA 17
18     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0 18
19     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1 19
20     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0 20
```

To the Rossi.long data

```
> head(Rossi.long,30)
     start stop arrest.time week arrest fin age race wexp mar paro prio educ id covariate.1
1.1      0    1           0   20      1   0  27    1    0   0    1    3    3  1           0
1.2      1    2           0   20      1   0  27    1    0   0    1    3    3  1           0
1.3      2    3           0   20      1   0  27    1    0   0    1    3    3  1           0
1.4      3    4           0   20      1   0  27    1    0   0    1    3    3  1           0
1.5      4    5           0   20      1   0  27    1    0   0    1    3    3  1           0
1.6      5    6           0   20      1   0  27    1    0   0    1    3    3  1           0
1.7      6    7           0   20      1   0  27    1    0   0    1    3    3  1           0
1.8      7    8           0   20      1   0  27    1    0   0    1    3    3  1           0
1.9      8    9           0   20      1   0  27    1    0   0    1    3    3  1           0
1.10     9   10           0   20      1   0  27    1    0   0    1    3    3  1           0
1.11    10   11           0   20      1   0  27    1    0   0    1    3    3  1           0
1.12    11   12           0   20      1   0  27    1    0   0    1    3    3  1           0
1.13    12   13           0   20      1   0  27    1    0   0    1    3    3  1           0
1.14    13   14           0   20      1   0  27    1    0   0    1    3    3  1           0
1.15    14   15           0   20      1   0  27    1    0   0    1    3    3  1           0
1.16    15   16           0   20      1   0  27    1    0   0    1    3    3  1           0
1.17    16   17           0   20      1   0  27    1    0   0    1    3    3  1           0
1.18    17   18           0   20      1   0  27    1    0   0    1    3    3  1           0
1.19    18   19           0   20      1   0  27    1    0   0    1    3    3  1           0
1.20    19   20           1   20      1   0  27    1    0   0    1    3    3  1           0
2.1      0    1           0   17      1   0  18    1    0   0    1    8    4  2           0
2.2      1    2           0   17      1   0  18    1    0   0    1    8    4  2           0
2.3      2    3           0   17      1   0  18    1    0   0    1    8    4  2           0
2.4      3    4           0   17      1   0  18    1    0   0    1    8    4  2           0
2.5      4    5           0   17      1   0  18    1    0   0    1    8    4  2           0
2.6      5    6           0   17      1   0  18    1    0   0    1    8    4  2           0
2.7      6    7           0   17      1   0  18    1    0   0    1    8    4  2           0
2.8      7    8           0   17      1   0  18    1    0   0    1    8    4  2           0
2.9      8    9           0   17      1   0  18    1    0   0    1    8    4  2           0
2.10     9   10           0   17      1   0  18    1    0   0    1    8    4  2           1
```

Is it possible to perform this exact transformation using the `reshape` or any other data transformation package?

UPDATE: The `Rcmdr` script is runnable only within `Rcmdr`

Comment: Its not a duplicate because this is a case of **survival data** explicitely.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta Please read my question carefully before you decide to do 2 Off-topic comments, vote for closure and flag as duplicate (all within 1 minute).

Comment: How many rows does Rossi.long contain?

Comment: 19809 rows and 15 variables

Comment: @ECII,  you are correct. I moved through a little too quickly there.  My apologies

Comment: Are you saying you get errors with the script I pointed you to? (I did not, so you really should clarify what the current status of your efforts is.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'unfold' function is located here (as documented in the pdf you linked to:

http://socserv.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Companion/scripts/appendix-cox.R

The script does *not* require Rcmdr. It would require `car` (which in turn loads `MASS` and `nnet` but if you have Rcmdr then you must have `car`) and it does load `survival` which is a recommended package and should be available in all installations. It runs to completion without error in R 3.0.0 beta and I strongly suspect it would have run to completion in R 2.15.x.

Comment: It runs very well, thank you for the idea. Out of curiosity is it possible to accomplish the same using a more conventional approach (reshape, plyr etc)

Comment: I doubt that it would be possible with `base::reshape` since it appears the strategy is to create extra rows whose counts depend on varying event-time values. I cannot really speak to using reshape2 or plyr functions, but it is seems unlikely to me to be a simple `melt` task.